# Creating an object of a class in another class in C++

Tags: c++, class, subclass

I have a class ID3 and a class Tree. An object of Class Tree is used in ID3 and its showing an error that Tree is not declared.

Code looks like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class ID3 {
public:
      string v[];
      int x;
public:
     double Hi(Tree data)
    {
        int y=x-1;
    }
};
class Tree{
         Tree();
}
```

Comment: Note that `string v[];` is not standard C++. Use `vector<string> v;` to make your code portable.

Answer (score 6):

You need to forward declare `Tree` before using it in `ID3`, otherwise the compiler doesn't know what `Tree` is:

```
class Tree;

class ID3 {
...
```

If you need to use an *instance* of `Tree` somewhere then you need to have the full definition of `Tree` before that point, for example:

```
class Tree {
    Tree();
};

class ID3 {
...
    double Hi(Tree data) {
        // do something with 'data'
        int y=x-1;
    }
};
```

For more information about when to use forward declarations, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration).

Answer (score 2):

In general, C++ is compiled from top to bottom. So if the class ID3 needs the class Tree, Tree must be defined before ID3. Just put the class Tree before ID3 and it should be fine.

Comment: It doesn't need to be *defined*, it's enough to just *declare* it.

Answer (score 0):

Forward deceleration of `Tree` will do the job. At the point where you used `Tree instance` in `ID3`, the compiler knows nothing about your `Tree` class, compiling process goes from up to bottom.